# Installing Ubuntu from USB does not find SSD

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, ssd

I have a Dell Precision 5520 laptop on which I am trying to install Ubuntu.

When I insert my USB installer of Ubuntu, I get a message of "you need at least 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 2.1 GB."

The USB stick I'm using is about that size. It looks like the installer doesn't recognize my drive. How do I tell Ubuntu I have a hard drive?

I looked in BIOS, and it shows an SSD in the M.2 PCIe slot, but there's also no drive selected as the "Primary Hard Drive."

[image: BIOS drive data]

Update: running `sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Disk /dev'` confusingly returns two small disks:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.5 GiB
Disk /dev/sda: 1.9 GiB
```

Neither of these are my SSD, but I'm not sure where the second one could be coming from.

Comment: Can you see the drive when booting into the live version?

Comment: Dell typically needs UEFI update, SSD firmware update & change from RAID or Intel RST to AHCI for drive. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln151664/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en Possibly similar models:  Dell Precision 5530
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420905
Dell 5230 with 3 m2 drives.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2406057

Comment: @oldfred, your link got me pointed in the right direction! Thanks.

Comment: Note if dual booting with Windows, you need to first add AHCI driver into Windows. Or temporarily change back to RAID/Intel RST, and add AHCI driver into Windows. Then reset to AHCI.

Answer (score 5):

In Dell's system BIOS (accessed by tapping F2 repeatedly on boot up), I had to  change the "SATA" setting to AHCI. The RAID option was selected instead, somehow. I rebooted and the installer found a place large enough to install.

@oldfred pointed me in the direction of [this Dell support article](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln299303/loading-ubuntu-on-systems-using-pcie-m2-drives?lang=en) that made that recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution :-)